# Is DNA transcription inactive during mitosis ie no proteins are made? How does the cell survive?

Tags: dna, molecular-genetics, transcription

I've read that during mitosis, DNA exists as heterochromatin, a form that is unable to be accessed for transcription.

Does this mean no new proteins are made during what can be 20% of a cell's life?  How does the cell survive?

Comment: To make proteins you  just need mRNAs. And most of the synthesis (transcription) is done in the S-phase, including the mRNAs required for later stages.

Comment: Consider two values, the average half-life of an mRNA, and the average half-life of a protein.  A cell may not need to transcribe it's essential genes non-stop.